# How to call a view upon pressing a button in another view?

Tags: iphone

How to call a view upon pressing a button in another view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you init your button:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickedButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then in a seperate function:

```
-(void)clickedButton:(id)selector {
    // delete as appropriate
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    // or
    [self.view addSubview:theView];
    // or
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: No problem. :) Whereabouts in birmingham? Do you have twitter?

Comment: Alvechurch..team of 3 ppl...iphone app developers..jinnashravan(twitter)

Comment: cool :) I'm from a company in the Jewellery Quarter. :) I've added you on twitter (I think) :p

Comment: yup I did to...How long have you been in iphone app development?